# WebRequest - GetRequestStream timing out with exception

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, put

I'm writing this short module where I have to modify an addressed resource with a PUT method. I'm using the `WebRequest` class to make this URI request and the `GetRequestStream()` to get the stream to write to.
However, it seems that after a couple of successful method calls (and using the PUT to modify resources) via this method below, my application hangs and then throws a `WebException: The request timed out.` error. Here's what the code looks like:

```
public void SendOffMessageToResource(int res_ID){
        var httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create ("http://192.168.x.x/api/sample_user/resources/1/state");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) //here's where the VS seems to take a long long time to step over to the next line when the error happens.
        {
            string json = "{\"on\":false}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
    }
```

I am already disposing the StreamWriter. I'm not even using the `GetResponse()` method, because all I need to do on this URI is actually modify the addressed resource with `PUT` method. I am not sure why it still throws an error and hangs the application. The search of previous threads only revealed that people should be using `using` statements to dispose resources, but I'm already doing that I think or perhaps I'm missing something? Do I always need to use `GetResponse()` to complete the request and dispose that always in addition to this?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I always need to use GetResponse() to complete the request and dispose that always in addition to this?

Yes, just that.